# Travelling with my Old Passport with UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, international-travel, filipino-citizens

My Philippine passport will expire in March 2017 and my UK visa that is valid until Nov. 2016 has been stamped on it. I am now processing a new passport and my question is can I travel with my old passport with UK visa on it together with my new passport?

I am planning to visit the UK by third week of September.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. See [Transfer your visa to a new passport](https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa):

> **You don’t have to transfer your visa - you can carry both your old and
>   new passports when travelling to or from the UK instead**.

Note: while they're not explicit about this, a typical rule is that this only works IF you did not change your name or citizenship.

The airlines know that, but Philippine passport control might not (and try to avoid flying out of Manila, where the passport control seem to give the most hassle to Filipinos). Carry a printout from this site with you.

Comment: Does Philippine passport control check Filipinos' documents against entry requirements for their foreign destinations? On what grounds?

Comment: Yes, they do. Apparently there is a law in Philippines against human trafficking, which gives passport control power to prevent Filipinos from leaving, if there is a legitimate reason to suspect they would be trafficked.